# Do you create multiple .dbml/.edmx file for large database when using LINQ2SQL or Entity Framework?

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework

When creating *.dbml/.edmx for a database which has a lot of tables, do you use multiple .dbml /*.edmx file or just a single giant file?

Any pro/cons for splitting the model into multiple file?

Thanks,
J.W.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Linq-to-SQL, there are a number of alternatives which allow you to create more granular sets of files, rather than one single *HUGE* file.

Check out PLINQO - a CodeSmith template set - http://www.plinqo.com - very well done, allows you to update your model from the database, and creates one code file per object class.

Marc

Answer (score 1):

I just go for one per database. Then there are less contexts to manage and you won't ever face the scenario of realising that you need to create a relationship on two entities that you've put in separate files.